# What algorithm does OpenCV use in minAreaRect for finding bounding box?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I have used the code for finding bounding rectangle for a set of points and everything is working fine, but I want to understand how the function really works.

What algorithm OpenCV uses for finding the [minimum bounding rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle)?
I tried to find the answer in opencv documentation and the tutorials but didnt find anything.

I only found [this research paper](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MinimumAreaRectangle.pdf) that mentions some algorithms but nothing about OpenCV here.

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at the source code, it is open source!

Comment: according to parameter names and stuff it uses "rotating calipers" on the convex hull of the points: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/rotcalipers.cpp

Comment: Are you referring to `boundingRect` or `minAreaRect`? The Wikipedia link you give points towards the former, but that is a totally trivial algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes turns out rotating calipers is the algorithm used in minAreaRect.